# MySQL и дублирование первичного ключа

Tags: mysql, sql

Здрафствуйте. У меня такой вопрос. Есть таблица с полями `id` и `value`. Поле `id - NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, AUTO_INCREMENT.`

1) Можно ли как-нибудь сказать `MySQL` чтобы при добавлении новой строки с повторяющимся `id` он автоматически обновлял уже существующую строку.

2) То же самое, но когда первичным ключом являются сразу несколько полей в совокупности.

Comment: Почему нельзя сделать вместо insert update и указать where id = value?

Comment: Просто не известно существует ли такой `id` или нет.

Comment: Немного не по теме, но все-равно напишу.
На сколько я помню, если поле указано, как Primary Key, то NOT NULL писать не обязательно - это уже входит в ограничение Primay Key

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте конструкцию `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`:

```
INSERT INTO table (id,value) VALUES (1,2)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

[см. документацию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: @renegator, теперь можно тоже самое, но только по русски. Прокомментируйте ответ пожалуйста.

Comment: Народ, объясните же наконец что написано в этой статье. Или я один не говорю по-английски))??

Comment: во-первых, явное присвоение значение полю с автоинкрементом невозможно - сервер просто выругается
во-вторых. по русски в мануале MySQL сказано следующее - если вы укажете ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, и вставляемая строка повлечет дублирование уникального индекса или первичного ключа, то выполнится UPDATE той строки, значение ключа в котором повторяется.